# Array Methods in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to write a method which enables me to add numbers to arrays. If I enter something execpt 0 it will be the first number of the array. The next one(except 0) will be the second number. When I enter 0 the program will end.
For example ; 1,2,3,4,5,0 will show 1,2,3,4,5 but when I enter it I get 0,5,5,5,5. Can you help?

Here an updated version, free from errors.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class test
{
     public static int[] addToArray(int[] bag, int value)
     {
         int i; 
         for(i = 0; i <= bag.length - 1; i++)
         {
              bag[i] = value;
              if(bag[i] == 0)
              {
                   return bag;
              }

         }
         return bag;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           int[] bag = new int[5];
           int i, value;
           i = 0;
           System.out.println("Enter the values : ");
           do
           {
                value = scan.nextInt();
                addToArray(bag, value);               
           }
           while(bag[i] != 0);

           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bag)); 
       }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Where did you declare "scan" variable ?

Comment: Consider using java.util.List

Comment: Can you look it again I got rid of errors.

Comment: Your logic is bit wrong. Did you try to dry run your logic? Just dry run it with an input and you should find, where you need to do the changes.

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You are looping through array every time you enter a new value. 5 was the last value that you entered and when you entered 5, it looped through the whole array and assigned the value 5 to the array elements. Remove the for loop inside addToArray method and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved it. The problem is in every loop in redefine the whole array so it will all print the last number I entered before 0. Thank you all for showing me this problem. I solved by adding another parameter to the method. The index parameter "i". Now, in the loop in won't start from zero. It will start from where it stopped so I can define the empty arrays without redefining the previous ones. Thank you all for helping.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class test
{
  public static int[] addToArray(int[] bag, int value, int i)
  {
    int j; 
    for(j = i; j <= bag.length - 1; j++)
    {
        bag[j] = value;
        if(bag[j] == 0)
        {
            for(; j <= bag.length - 1; j++)
            bag[j] = 0;
            return bag;
        }

      }
      return bag;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] bag = new int[5];
     int i, value;
     i = 0;
     System.out.println("Enter the values : ");
     do
     {
         value = scan.nextInt();
         addToArray(bag, value, i);
         i++;               
     }
     while(value != 0);

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bag)); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `addToArray` method is replacing the whole array every time is called. This is what the for loop is doing

```
for(i = 0; i <= bag.length - 1; i++) {
    bag[i] = value;
    ...
}
```

When you enter 0 then this code:

```
bag[i] = value
if(bag[i] == 0) {
  return bag;
}
```

Will set the `bag[0] = 0` and then the `if` will succeed and return the bag.

What you need is to find in which position of the array you should be adding this value

```
public static int findNextEmptyPosition(bag) { .... }

...
int nextPosition = findNextEmptyPosition(bag);
bag[nextPosition] = value;
...

//check is the value is zero and stop your while loop.
```